# How to replace the usage of LD_PRELOAD with dlopen()?

Tags: c++, linux, shared-libraries

I'm working on c++ with shared library usage.

Currently I'm using "LD_PRELOAD" and set this environment variable using setenv() 
call.
But I want to use dlopen() API to load shared library. That should work same as like setting environment variable (i.e. LD_PRELOAD) using setenv().

can i use dlopen() to get above requirements? or there is difference in the library loading using LD_PRELOAD and dlopen()?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about this, but maybe RTLD_GLOBAL flag for dlopen() will fit your needs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure about this, but as I understand it using `LD_PRELOAD` makes the program loader load all libraries, first, then the library specified by `LD_PRELOAD` and last your application. This makes it possible to override system libraries with your own.

Using `dlopen` loads the shared object after your program is loaded, so can not be used to override system objects.

If the environment variable have to be set for the program to work correctly, then it has to be set before the program is loaded, either in the shell or by your `LD_PRELOAD` file. If the program doesn't need the environment variable immediately then you can either set it in the program or in the "on-load" function in the shared object loaded by `dlopen`.

Comment: As I understand it that's correct, so I'll be interested if someone has a different take.

Comment: Can you 'dlopen' the library as if there were no `LD_PRELOAD`? I.e. if you want to override system objects for your program but not for the dlopened lib?